# Report Builder 3.0 Line Chart Labels

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0, reportbuilder

I would like to only show the last data point label on a line chart per series.  Anyone know how how I can hide the labels except for the last data point either using the Visible Property or the Label values?

Comment: It is possible if you can determine the last value in x-axis, suppose your category groups field is the month number then you can use an expression like this in the visible property: `IIF(MAX(Fields!Month.Value)=Fields!Month.Value,True,False)`

Comment: My chart uses Chart Filters and not Dataset filters so I am not sure how to get the Max x value from the chart itself.  Is there a way to get the last X axis datapoint?

Comment: What is the expression you used for filter your chart?